# Query that converts several units to TB as well as performs calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a dataset, df, where I would like to convert one column from Bytes to Terabytes, as well as Megabytes to TB.

```
Free                    Total
30,000,000,000,000.00   40,000,000
40,000,000,000,000.00   50,000,000
```

****Bytes to TB - divide by 1024/1024/1024/1024
Megabytes to TB - divide by 1024/1024****

Desired Outcome

```
Free    Total   Used
30      40      10
40      50      10
```

This is what I am doing

```
SELECT 
    Free /1024/ 1024/ 1024 /1024 AS Free1, 
    Total /1024 /1024 AS Total1, 
    (Total1-Free1) As Used
FROM df
```

However, I am not getting my desired result. Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: OK, so what is your question?

Comment: Formatting matters, especially in questions. You didn't ask a specific question, and the part that causes an error was hidden outside the visible part of the code

Comment: `I am not getting my desired result.` that's not an error message or a problem description. It means that you get some result, just not the one you expected. In reality though, you should be getting an error

Comment: I see- I will update the post with the error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reuse the aliases in the same scope. Instead, you need to repeat the expressions (or use a subquery or CTE):

```
select 
    free / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 /1024 as free1, 
    total / 1024 / 1024 as total1, 
    (total / 1024 / 1024 - free / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024) as used
from df
```

We can factorize the computation a little:

```
select 
    free / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 /1024 as free1, 
    total / 1024 / 1024 as total1, 
    (total - free / 1024 / 1024)  / 1024 / 1024 as used
from df
```

Note that, if you are storing the values as integers to start with, the above query will do *integer division* (that is, the result is truncated to integer). If that's not what you want, then just turn one of the operands to a decimal, as in:

```
free / 1024.0 / 1024 / 1024 /1024 as free1,
```

Comment: ok I will try this- I was not seeing my desired result with my code that I used. Thanks

Comment: One should mention that hard disk vendors define KB as `1000` not `1024` to make their drives look bigger. Even though they used `1024` in the early days. And try to persuade us that everyone else got it wrong, by introducing KiB. Even though they used 1024 in the 1990s, especially for their floppy disk products

Answer (score 2):

If you do have an expression that you want to repeat often, I find that using a `VALUES` table construct in the `FROM` works well. I wouldn't really say it's needed here, but this might be an overly simplified example. For what you have, however, it would look like this:

```sql
SELECT V.free1,
       V.total1,
       V.total1-V.free1 as used
FROM dbo.df
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(df.free/1024/1024/1024/1024, df.total/1024/1024))V(free1,total1);
```